# Manipulating google calendar DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I'm using jQuery to manipulate the Create Event view of Google Calendar.

I'm trying to set the start date&time as well as the end date&time via jQuery, but when actually creating the event it uses the default values instead of mine.

I'm guessing the required events are not being triggered.

I managed to get the date to work using:

`$('input[id$=-sd]').first().trigger('focus').val(startDate).blur()`

But the time just doesn't get updated. Currently trying to use:

`$('input[id$=-st]').first().attr('value', startTime).val(startTime).trigger('change')`

But no luck.

Any ideas how can I imitate a user setting real input and then focusing out of the input element? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using vanilla Events instead of triggering jQuery events.

```
$('input[id$=-st]').first().attr('value', startTime).val(startTime)[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

I've found that I had similar issues when trying to use the jQuery .click() function in Google Calendar from a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed was the problem. Also I set bubbling ON and cancel OFF with initEvent, did the trick.